# How to change Label color in flex Using CSS?

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex

In my Flex Application i'm using `Main.mxml` `sub.mxml`

In Sub.mxml have code.

```
<mx:Label x="24" y="33" text="User ID"/>
<mx:Label x="24" y="59" text="Password"/>
```

And in my Main.Mxml file Writing CSS

```
mx|Label{
        fontFamily: Calibri;
        fontSize: 12;
        color: #000000;
    }
```

But Label not visiable ... is this Css wrong?

Comment: Does it makes your labels visible if you remove style declaration?

Comment: write the code with in <Style>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems ok. This simple example works:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[ import mx.events.FlexEvent; ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Style>
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    mx|Label {
        fontFamily: Calibri;
        fontSize: 12;
        color: #000000;
    }
</fx:Style>
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:Label text="asdasdasd">
    </mx:Label>
    <mx:Label text="sdas">
    </mx:Label>
</mx:VBox>
</s:Application>
```

Davide